# Book about a couple found frozen in ice by a doctor/scientist who come back to life

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book about a couple found frozen in ice coming back to life.

A doctor/scientist during an expedition discovers a frozen box in which a man and a woman are found. The man goes missing, and the woman is still alive. The doctor devises an injection for the woman to live. The missing man comes back and asks the woman to go with him She refuses and asks the man to take this medicine but refuses and during the fight that follows, falls into the water. As the water touches him, he freezes to death again.

PS: This is a very vague description of a book I read; I cannot remember the title. Does this description strike a bell to anyone? I read this book about 10 years back. It is an English book.
(The book is not the ICE PEOPLE. It has a similar start but this is not the book.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Do you remember _when_ you read this book? In what language? Could you please [edit] in any such details you might recall?

Comment: Also, you tagged this [vampire]; are there any vampires involved? I've removed the tag but please out it back if it's relevant.

Comment: Hai , i read this book about 10 years back. It was in english.

Comment: i dont remember any other details

Comment: could you please [edit] your question to include these details?

Answer (score 9):

The premise vaguely reminds me of [*The Ice People*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_People_(Barjavel_novel)) by René Barjavel, even though some of the details you mention don't match up.

The book tells the story of a group of scientists who receive a signal coming from deep within the ice while working in the Arctic. They decide to start excavating the ice, and find a man and a woman asleep in a room. This part matches what you described.

Some parts don't match :

- They wake up the woman by warming her up, not by "devising a medicine;"
- The man never goes missing;
- Spoiler if you want to read the book:

  > The man does die in the end, but not by freezing to death, rather the man needs a blood transfusion and the woman, who is the only one with the appropriate blood type, refuses to give the transfusion.

Comment: Excellent S-F book, despite its age. Highly recommended. "La nuit des temps" is the French title.

Comment: Hai @sol . No the book is not the ICE PEOPLE. It has a similar start but this is not the book.Thanks